# how to define extra method for rails form text_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After removing `dimensions` from my table, my scaffolded view hit this error: `undefined method 'dimensions'` for this code:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :dimensions %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :dimensions %>
  </div>
```

I want to keep this dimention field in the form and in the controller I want to split this string into length, width, height.

Now what should I do?

Comment: use `attr_accessor` and make setters and getters

Comment: can you post format of dimensions for split?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a virtual attribute, which is done using `attr_accessor`

`attr_accessor` is a ruby method for creating `getter` and `setter` methods. This basically means you're able to create a series of `virtual attributes` for use in your `models`

```
Class Table < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :dimensions
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this into your `model` to keep this attribute `dimensions` as virtual attributes

```
 Class ModelName < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :dimensions
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to use it in the controller then instead of using `f.text_field :dimensions`, use `text_field_tag :dimensions`. You can access this attribute in the action directly by using `params[:dimensions]`